# Can't get sub directories of a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE result

Tags: android

Using the latest Kotlin and Android versions I can't seem to get the sub directories in a directory the user selects via `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`

I'm firing the intent with:

```
private fun openDirectory(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
        putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }

    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

The result launcher doesn't do much but pass the data to another function where I'm trying to see all the files/folders in the selected directory:

```
private fun walkTree(uri: Uri) {
    val documentFile: DocumentFile? = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(requireContext(), uri)

    documentFile?.listFiles()?.forEach { file ->
        Timber.d("File: " + file.uri)
    }
}
```

However when I run this, all I'm seeing is the top level directories in the directory I select and not the files inside the directories.

Do I need to recursively call this? I thought the fromTreeUri would take care of this for me?

Comment: Indeed recursive as always. Did you ever see it different? File.listFiles() needs recursive use too.

Comment: No, but new to android and kotlin so made a bunch of assumptions :D